# Eraser tool for GIF editor

Tags: c#, performance, image, wpf

I am making a GIF editor in C#, and I am currently working on the eraser tool. I am not sure what I can do to make it more efficient, because when I make the thickness (diameter) more than 30 (pixels) it starts to get a bit slow.

```
if (click && eraserSelected)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => b = imageBox.Source as WriteableBitmap));
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => endPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(imageBox)));

                System.Windows.Media.Color color;
                System.Windows.Point[] linePixels = FindPixels.Line(startPoint, endPoint).ToArray();
                int[][][] pixels = new int[linePixels.Length][][];

                for (int i = 0; i < linePixels.Length; i++)
                    pixels[i] = FindPixels.Circle(thickness, (int)linePixels[i].X, (int)linePixels[i].Y);

                Bitmap originalFrame = gifFrames.GetOriginalFrame();

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((() =>
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < pixels.Length; j++)
                        for (int i = 0; i < pixels[j][0].Length; i++)
                            if (pixels[j][0][i] < pixelsEdited[0].Count() && pixels[j][0][i] >= 0 && pixels[j][1][i] < pixelsEdited.Count() && pixels[j][1][i] >= 0)
                                if (!pixelsEdited[pixels[j][1][i]][pixels[j][0][i]])
                                {
                                    color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(originalFrame.GetPixel(pixels[j][0][i], pixels[j][1][i]).R, originalFrame.GetPixel(pixels[j][0][i], pixels[j][1][i]).G, originalFrame.GetPixel(pixels[j][0][i], pixels[j][1][i]).B);
                                    try
                                    {
                                        b.SetPixel(pixels[j][0][i], pixels[j][1][i], color);
                                        pixelsEdited[pixels[j][1][i]][pixels[j][0][i]] = true;
                                    }
                                    catch { }
                                }
                }));

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => startPoint = endPoint));
            }).Start();
        }
```

That is the code for the eraser tool itself. Here is the code for the `FindPixels.Line()` and `FindPixels.Circle()` functions:

```
class FindPixels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds all the pixels that are within a circle of a given diameter, and center
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="diameter"></param>
    /// <param name="centerX"></param>
    /// <param name="centerY"></param>
    /// <returns>All the pixels within a circle</returns>
    public static int[][] Circle(int diameter, int centerX, int centerY)
    {
        int radius = diameter / 2;
        List<int> pixelsX = new List<int>();
        List<int> pixelsY = new List<int>();

        for (int x = centerX - radius; x < centerX + radius; x++)
        {
            for (int y = centerY - radius; y < centerY + radius; y++)
            {
                double dx = x - centerX;
                double dy = y - centerY;
                double distanceSquared = dx * dx + dy * dy;

                if (distanceSquared <= radius * radius)
                {
                    int distance = y - (centerY - radius);
                    for (int i = 0; i < diameter - distance * 2; i++)
                    {
                        pixelsX.Add(x);
                        pixelsY.Add(y + i);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        int[][] pixels = { pixelsX.ToArray(), pixelsY.ToArray() };
        return pixels;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds all pixels that form a line
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startPoint"></param>
    /// <param name="endPoint"></param>
    /// <returns>All points within the two points given</returns>
    public static List<Point> Line(Point p0, Point p1)
    {
        int x0 = (int)p0.X;
        int y0 = (int)p0.Y;
        int x1 = (int)p1.X;
        int y1 = (int)p1.Y;
        int dx = Math.Abs(x1 - x0);
        int dy = Math.Abs(y1 - y0);

        int sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
        int sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1;

        int err = dx - dy;

        var points = new List<Point>();

        while (true)
        {
            points.Add(new Point(x0, y0));
            if (x0 == x1 && y0 == y1) break;

            int e2 = 2 * err;
            if (e2 > -dy)
            {
                err = err - dy;
                x0 = x0 + sx;
            }
            if (e2 < dx)
            {
                err = err + dx;
                y0 = y0 + sy;
            }
        }

        return points;
    }
}
```

What I was thinking was instead of drawing a bunch of circles on each pixel of the line, I draw the start and end point and then do a rectangle to connect them, but how would I find the points connecting them.

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

The red points are what I am having trouble finding, and all the points withing the pink outline are what I would change.

Comment: Nice drawing! If that method is indeed more efficient and a reviewer happens to suggest it and even give you some code for it, that's great - but by asking on this site you're asking for feedback on any & all aspects of *the code you're posting*, not the code you *would have liked* to write and put up for review. Does your code work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is inefficient because you are trying to do a lot of low-level work yourselves instead of relying on existing functionality available in .NET framework, which is most likely optimized for low-level work. Here are the classes/methods I would try:

- `System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)` method to create a `Graphics` object which provides methods to draw on a bitmap;
- `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath` object to define the shape which you drawn in your question;
- `System.Drawing.Graphics.FillPath(Brush, GraphicsPath)` to fill the shape needed.

Defining the shape drawn is a pretty simple trigonometric exercise: you have coordinates of your starting and ending circles (x1,y1 and x2,y2), and a bunch of similar right triangles. Here is the calculation of your points:

```
var alpha = Math.Atan2(startPoint.Y - endPoint.Y, endPoint.X - startPoint.X); //measuring angle from X axis in clockwise direction

var shift = new Vector(radius * Math.Sin(alpha), -radius * Math.Cos(alpha));
var points = new[] //points specified on drawing
{
    startPoint + shift,
    startPoint - shift,
    endPoint + shift,
    endPoint - shift
};
```

What you need to complete is to define a `GraphicsPath` which consists of 2 180-degree arcs and 2 lines, and pass it to `Graphics.FillPath` method